# Run Responder using proxychains on a remote network

Tags: network, penetration-test, proxychains

Is it possible to run `Responder` as a flag in the `proxychains` program when I do some penetration testing activities, such as nmap and crackmapexec in the enumeration process?

Responder command example : `sudo proxychains responder -i 192.168.0.111 -I eth0`

Comment: What does the documentation for proxychains say?

Answer (score 1):

The `-I eth0` part of the command you're running refers to a local network interface. It's main mode of operation is as a network listener. You can run it on a local or remote machine, but not tunnel it.

Comment: so I can't use it as a flag in the proxychains ?